# what is the best way to compare two complex java object and generate event depending upon comparision

Tags: java

I have a requirement to compare two complex object, e:g

```
Policy{

 Private Vehicle-information info1;
 private Driver-information info2;
 ...
}
```

I have two populated instance of this class. I want to compare those instance and depending upon difference I need to show them in UI marked in colors using some flag.

What is the best way to compare these objects. Can we achieve it using `XML` because java code will be complex.

Comment: How complex are they? Do you have some kind of serialization format already? If JSON, I have a solution...

Answer (score 3):

Override the [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method in your `Policy` class. Then you can check for equality like:

```
if(object1.equals(object2)) { 
  // do something
}
```

Implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and override the [compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method if you need to order the objects.

Comment: Yes there is: highlight the differences!

Comment: In the UI, it says so... Don't be so dull as to not extrapolate ;)

Comment: .equals() is a binary contract, OP wants differences explained. .equals() cannot do that.

Comment: See my answer to see what I mean, and what the OP certainly means

Answer (score 0):

One solution: use Jackson to serialize your objects as JSON, then use [this](https://github.com/fge/json-patch): it is a Java implementation of JSON Patch which also can generate *differences* between two JSONs as JSON Patches.

Which means you can know what has changed and where. And since this is JSON, you can send the result to your browser and have it handled by some JavaScript code easily. Unlike XML!

Comment: thanks for idea,but in this case also there will be complex if-else condition as my scenario consists of complex object comparison with outcomes depending upon that